# modify_at to remove NA values in each element in a list

Tags: r, na, purrr

I have a big list of small datasets like this:

```
>> my_list

[[1]]
# A tibble: 6 x 2
   Year FIPS 
  <dbl> <chr>
1  2015 12001
2  2015 51013
3  2015 12081
4  2015 12115
5  2015 12127
6  2015 42003

[[2]]
# A tibble: 9 x 2
   Year FIPS 
  <dbl> <chr>
1  2017 04013
2  2017 10003
3  2017 NA   
4  2017 25005
5  2017 25009
6  2017 25013
7  2017 25017
8  2017 25021
9  2017 25027

...
```

I want to remove the NAs from each tibble using `modify_at` because looks like is a clean way to do it. This is my try:

```
my_list %>% modify_at(c("FIPS"), drop_na)
```

I tried also with `na.omit`, but I get the same error in both cases:

```
Error: character indexing requires a named object
```

Can anyone help me here, please? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please share your data using `dput` function

Comment: You're applying `drop_na` to the list itself, not the elements of the list.  Try `lapply(my_list, drop_na)`.

Comment: @Limey it works so smooth... thanks! So, there is no option to use `modify_at` in this case?

Comment: I think `modify_at()` would only be useful here combined with something like `modify_depth()` so you work within each data.frame instead of at the whole list level.  That seems complicated compared to a `lapply()` or `map()` loop. :)

Comment: @Limey is right, you apply `drop_na` on the whole data set since it removes an entire row containing `NA` values. So `modify_at` is of no use here. But you can use `mylist %>% modify(drop_na)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating some data.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mylist <-
  list(tibble(a = c(1, 2, NA),
              b = c(2, 2, 2)),
       tibble(c = rep(1, 5),
              d = sample(c(NA, 2), 5, replace = TRUE)))
```

The `.at` argument in `purrr::modify_at()` specifies the list element to modify, not the column within the dataframe nested in the list. `purrr::modify()` works for your purposes.

```r
modify(mylist, drop_na)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       c     d
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     1     2
#> 3     1     2
#> 4     1     2
```

`purrr::map()` also works. Since your input and output are both `list` objects, `map()` is sufficient here, while `modify()` would be preferred if your input is of another `class` than a regular `list` and you want to conserve that `class` attribute for the output.

```r
map(mylist, drop_na)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       c     d
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     1     2
#> 3     1     2
#> 4     1     2
```

`base R`

```r
lapply(mylist, na.omit)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       c     d
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     1     2
#> 3     1     2
#> 4     1     2
```